# Express the permutation $\sigma = \left({}^1_5\,{}^2_8 \,{}^3_3\,{}^4_6\,{}^5_7\,{}^6_4\,{}^7_1\,{}^8_2\right)$ as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$
I was hoping to get some feedback.

> Consider the permutation
>   $$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
> 5&8&3&6&7&4&1&2
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   (a) Describe the orbits of $\sigma$.
>   (b) Express $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles, and then as a product of transpositions.
>   (c) What is the order of $\sigma$? Explain.

---

(a) The orbits of $\sigma$ are $\{1,5,7\}, \{2,8\},\{3\},\{4,6\}$.

(b) As a product of disjoint cycles: $\sigma = (1\;5\;7)(2\;8)(3)(4\;6)$
As a product of transpositions: $\sigma = (1\;7)(1\;5)(2\;8)\boxed{(3)\,}(4\,6)$
I am not sure if I should include $(3)$ since transpositions are cycles of length $2$.

(c) I don't know what the order of a permutation is. My first guess was that it is the number of orbits of $\sigma$. So I would say $4$. But then I saw a post that used the $\lcm$. I infer that it is the $\lcm$ of the lengths of the orbits of $\sigma$; hence $\lcm(2,3) = 6$. Is this correct? If so, why is it the $\lcm$?

Comment: the order is least common multiple of $3,2,1,2$ corresponding with the lengths of the disjoint cycles in the product. So the order is $6$. It is correct to leave $(3)$ out of the product of transpositions.

Comment: Is that under the same topic as [this](https://theinfosphere.org/Futurama_theorem) ?

Comment: @BCLC Possibly? Haha.

Comment: When you write a permutation as a product of cycles - i.e. like this $(1,2)(3,4,2)$ - it is generally agreed that all the elements that do not appear are left fixed. So, you *can* write the $1$-cycles (which are the fixed points), but you do not need to. If you want, you may as well notice that $(3)=id$ and eliminate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) -- Correct.

(b) -- No, you don't need to include $(3)$.

(c) -- The order of a permutation $\sigma$ is the smallest positive integer $\ell$ so that $\sigma^\ell=1$. Since the disjoints cycles of $\sigma$ are mutually commutative, $\ell$ is divisible by the order of each cycle. Therefore, $\ell$ is the l.c.m of those orders, which are exactly the lengths of the cycles.

Comment: I understand what $\sigma^\ell(a)$ means, but what does $\sigma^\ell = 1$ mean?

Comment: $1$ means the identity permutation, which fixes all the letters $1,2,\dots,n$.